# error while restarting integrated weblogic server on jdev

Tags: windows, jdeveloper, weblogic-10.x

I am getting the below error on trying to restart the IWLS on JDEV

> C:\Users\c-sutipirn\system11.1.2.2.39.61.83.1\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
>   [waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
>   \Java\jdk1.7.0_25 was unexpected at this time. Process exited.

my path variable is set to:

> C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.0\Windows Performance
>   Toolkit\;C:\app\client\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24

Any help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

11.1.2.2 needs JDK 6 to work.
Upgrade to either 12c or at least 11.1.2.4 and you will be able to run with JDK7.

Comment: i removed all the entries related to jdk in path variable and classpath,deleted java_home variable and was able to restart

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that WebLogic server starting scripts (as startWebLogic.cmd and setDomainEnv.cmd ) refers system variables as %JAVA_HOME% (or %CLASSPATH%) without quotation e.g. "%JAVA_HOME%".

> "%1 was unexpected at this time"

is shell error result caused by spaces in used system variables.

I'm solving similar problem with WebLogic 12.1.x server and I do not know simple solution, start script is pretty complex and hard to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this can be related to the value of the **PATH environment variable**.

If it contains a path (with quotes) like `;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin";` (with a space) it will result in "Files was unexpected at this time".

Removing the quotes seems to resolve this (`;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;`) and using the short name could be an alternative (`;C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre7\bin;`, try **"dir /X"** to get the short name).

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue. Turned out %PATH% was too long and blew up in c:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\shortenPaths.cmd

In my case, I just commented out with REM as follows:

```
REM if NOT "%PATH%"=="" (
  call :handle_path
REM )
goto :EOF
```

PS: didn't see the EOF label so i also added :EOF at the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

I solved it through path variables changes for windows, by following this steps:

1. define `JAVA_HOME` and `MVN_HOME` first as new env viriables
2. Update Path and add new viariables: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and `%MVN_HOME%\bin`

Make sure you do not have nay other variables with a full path name like: C:\Program Files.

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble.
If you wanna create new Oracle domain on weblogic, you should make comments on line with loop (for) in Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\config.cmd. After that call config.cmd through cmd.